# useEffect warns about missing dependency which causes infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

The following code works perfectly :

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const Main = () => {

  const [ form, setForm ] = useState({
    error: {},
    data: {}
  });

  useEffect( () => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const promise = await fetch(`test.json`);
      const result = await promise.json();
      const newForm = {...form};
      newForm.data = result;
      setForm(newForm);
      console.log('executed');
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);  // *** I will speak to this [] second argument shortly in question below

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{Object.keys(form.data).length}</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

All it does is on component mount, grab a `test.json` file that has the content `{"data":"hello"}`. This works perfectly and does what I want.

However, in my console, I see the compiler complain with this message `Line 20:6:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'form'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps`. When I add `[ form ]` as the second argument to `useEffect` or if I delete the `[]` second argument from `useEffect`, then the `useEffect` goes into infinite loop.

Why is my compiler warning me of an issue and suggesting an action that causes an infinite loop?

Comment: It's your linter giving this warning and it's because it thinks that you have missed a dependency and things will be working in an unexpected manner. You can disable the lint rule (either for the line, the file or all together) or you can adjust your code to make it happy. To make it happy you could use the callback `setState` syntax i.e. `setForm(currentForm => { const newForm = {...currentForm}; newForm.data = result; return newForm; });` and remove the need to include `form` in the `useEffect`.

Comment: I went with the callback syntax!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error / warning is created by your linter.

The linter rule assumes that you have missed a variable that is external to the `useEffect` in the dependency array which would cause unexpected outcomes.

You could disable the lint rule for:

1. The line

```js
useEffect(() => {

}, []); // eslint-disable-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```

2. The rest of the file

```js
/* eslint-disable react-hooks/exhaustive-deps */
useEffect(() => {

}, []);
```

3. All files using your eslintrc file.

If you don't want to disable the rule you could swap to using the `setState` callback syntax which provides the current state as a parameter.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const Main = () => {

  const [ form, setForm ] = useState({
    error: {},
    data: {}
  });

  useEffect( () => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const promise = await fetch(`test.json`);
      const result = await promise.json();
      setForm(currentForm => {
        const newForm = {...currentForm};
        newForm.data = result;
        return newForm;
      });
      console.log('executed');
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{Object.keys(form.data).length}</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

This removes the need to include `form` in the useEffect.

As to the reason why the linter might think this is an issue, look at this example:

```
export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState({ a: 'Initial Value', b: null });
  const [control, setControl] = useState({ a: "Initial Value", b: null });

  useEffect(() => {
    const asyncFunc = () => {
        new Promise(resolve => {
          setTimeout(() => resolve(true), 2000) 
        })
        .then(() => {
          // The value of "data" will be the initial value from 
          // when the useEffect first ran.
          setData({...data, b: 'Async Updated'});

          // The value of "current" wille be the current value of
          // the "control" state.
          setControl(current => ({ ...current, b: "Async Updated" }));
        })
    };

    asyncFunc();
    
    // Update the data state while the async function has not
    // yet been completed.
    setData({ a: 'Changed Value', b: null });
    
    // Update the control state while the async function has not
    // yet been completed.
    setControl({ a: "Changed Value", b: null });
  }, []);

  // The data value will swap to "Changed Value" and then back 
  // to "Initial Value" (unexpected) once the async request is
  // complete.
  // As the control used the current value provided by the 
  // callback it is able to avoid this issue. 
  return (
    <div>
      Data:
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(data, null, "\t")}</pre>
      Control:
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(control, null, "\t")}</pre>
    </div>
  );
};
```

You can run this example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hmfddo